# protocol / POP issues: error: 'self' used before chaining to another self.init requirement:

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Trying to use this func during class initialization, so I can have the type name auto-added to the title:

```
func getTypeOf(_ object: Any) -> String {  
  return String(describing: type(of: object)) + ": "
}
```

I have it working well in a typical inheritance setup, but I'm working on switching to more of a POP / FP style:

```
import SpriteKit

//
// OOP Demo:
//
class IGEoop: SKSpriteNode {

  init(title: String) {
    super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blue, size: CGSize.zero)
    self.name = getTypeOf(self) + title
  }
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError() }
}

class PromptOOP: IGEoop {
}

// Works fine:
let zipOOP = PromptOOP(title: "hi oop")
print(zipOOP.name!)
```

This is the block I can't get working, and get the error message:

> error: 'self' used before chaining to another self.init requirement:

```
//
// POP Demo:
//
protocol IGEpop { init(title: String) }
extension IGEpop where Self: SKSpriteNode {
  init(title: String) {
    // error: 'self' used before chaining to another self.init requirement:
    self.name = getTypeOf(self) + title
  }
}

class PromptPOP: SKSpriteNode, IGEpop {
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError() }
}

// Errars:
let zipPOP = PromptOOP(title: "hi pop")
print(zipPOP.name!)
```

Any solutions or workarounds appreciated!

Comment: Did you try "chaining to another self.init requirement" (similar to what you did in your first example)?

Comment: @Hamish i tried a couple things but im not sure how to do it if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like in your inheritance example, you need to chain to another initialiser before being able to use `self`. So, for example, we could chain to `init(texture:color:size)`:

```
extension IGEpop where Self : SKSpriteNode {

    init(title: String) {
        self.init(texture: nil, color: .blue, size: .zero)
        self.name = getTypeOf(self) + title
    }
}
```

The only problem with this is that `PromptPOP` does *not* have an implemention of `init(texture:color:size)`. It defines an implementation of the designated initialiser `init(aCoder:)`, therefore it doesn't inherit `SKSpriteNode`'s designated initialisers.

Therefore you need to either remove the implementation of `init(aCoder:)` such that `PromptPOP` can inherit its superclass' designated initialisers, or provide an implementation of `init(texture:color:size)` – which in this case can simply chain to `super`:

```
class PromptPOP : SKSpriteNode, IGEpop {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError() }

    // note that I've marked the initialiser as being required, therefore ensuring
    // that it's available to call on any subclasses of PromptPOP.
    override required init(texture: SKTexture?, color: NSColor, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
    }
}
```

Although it's probably worth adding the initialiser you use in the protocol extension to the protocol requirements, thus *ensuring* that all conforming types implement it at compile time (otherwise you'll just get a runtime error if they don't).

```
protocol IGEpop {
    init(title: String)
    init(texture: SKTexture?, color: NSColor, size: CGSize)
}
```

Comment: ugh, this seems almost blatantly obvious now... it just never occurred to me to use `self.init(texture` because I've always used `super.init(texture`... but now I can see that this works because of the `where is` in the protocol. This particular error message didn't make it to the first page of Google, so hopefully this question will get some mileage :) Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help @Fluidity :)